# Global Variables in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a multi-page `MVVM` application that has a few ViewModels. (It's a hobby app, storing statistics and stuff)

The following classes are

- `GamePageViewModel`
- `MenuViewModel`
- `PlayersViewModel`
- `StartPagePresenter`
- `Controller` (This acts as a `PageSwitcher` and as the model that stores all of my `TableAdapters` from a database)

All of them have a few of the same variables

- `Universe`
- `Character`
- `Season`

What I'd like to do is move these variables to my `MainMenuViewModel` (which is the menubar on all of the pages), where you select Universe, Character, Season, etc, and they populate in the other ViewModels.

my `MenuViewModel` Class

```
    public class MenuViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        private DataView _Universes = Controller.UniverseTableAdapter.GetData().DefaultView;
        private DataRowView _SelectedUniverse;

        public DataView Universes
        {
            get { return _Universes; }
            set
            {
                _Universes = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("Universes");
            }
        }

        public DataRowView SelectedUniverse
        {
            get { return _SelectedUniverse; }
            set
            {
                _SelectedUniverse = value;
                Controller.SelectedUniverse = _SelectedUniverse;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedUniverse");
            }
        }

        public ICommand GoHome { get { return new DelegateCommand(NavigateHome); } }

        public ICommand GoPlayers { get { return new DelegateCommand(NavigatePlayers); } }

        public ICommand GoGame { get { return new DelegateCommand(NavigateGame); } }


        public void NavigateHome() { Controller.Switch(new StartPage()); }

        public void NavigatePlayers() { Controller.Switch(new PlayerPage()); }

        public void NavigateGame() { Controller.Switch(new GamePage()); }

    }
```

I thought I'd try to store them in the `Controller` Class like this, but not sure how I would send out the `RaisePropertyChangedEvent` Events to each of the ViewModels

```
    public static class Controller
    {

        #region Variables

        //Variables
        private static MainWindow _Window;

        private static MaddenDBDataSet _MaddenDB = new MaddenDBDataSet();
        private static CharacterTableAdapter _CharacterTableAdapter = new CharacterTableAdapter();
        private static FranchiseTableAdapter _FranchiseTableAdapter = new FranchiseTableAdapter();
        private static GamePlayerTableAdapter _GamePlayerTableAdatper = new GamePlayerTableAdapter();
        private static GameTableAdapter _GameTableAdapter = new GameTableAdapter();
        private static PersonTableAdapter _PersonTableAdapter = new PersonTableAdapter();
        private static SeasonTableAdapter _SeasonTableAdapter = new SeasonTableAdapter();
        private static UniverseTableAdapter _UniverseTableAdapter = new UniverseTableAdapter();
        private static UserYearTableAdapter _UserYearTableAdapter = new UserYearTableAdapter();
        private static CollegeTableAdapter _CollegeTableAdapter = new CollegeTableAdapter();
        private static view_PlayersTableAdapter _PlayerView = new view_PlayersTableAdapter();
        private static view_UniverseCharactersTableAdapter _UniverseCharacterView = new view_UniverseCharactersTableAdapter();
        private static UniverseCharacterTableAdapter _UniverseCharacterTableAdapter = new UniverseCharacterTableAdapter();
        private static view_ScheduleTableAdapter _ScheduleView = new view_ScheduleTableAdapter();
        private static view_YearsTableAdapter _YearView = new view_YearsTableAdapter();
        private static View_GameStatsTableAdapter _GameStatsView = new View_GameStatsTableAdapter();
        private static view_RegularSeasonTableAdapter _SeasonView = new view_RegularSeasonTableAdapter();
        private static view_PlayoffsTableAdapter _PlayoffsView = new view_PlayoffsTableAdapter();

        //Keep a tab of all of our ViewModels

        private static DataRowView _SelectedUniverse = null;
        public static DataRowView SelectedUniverse { get { return _SelectedUniverse; } set { _SelectedUniverse = value; } }

        #region Methods

        //Navigation
        public static void Switch(UserControl newPage)
        {
            _Window.Navigate(newPage);
        }

        public static void Switch(UserControl newPage, object state)
        {
            _Window.Navigate(newPage, state);
        }

        #endregion  

    }
```

Any pointers on storing global variables would be much appreciated!

Comment: Move those three things to a separate view model and share that instance with all your other view models (i.e. pass it to their constructors).

Comment: I tend to use a "ApplicationViewModel" as the top ViewModel. The ApplicationViewModel exposes all other ViewModels (wich tend to be focussed on one task). You can not really recycle the ApplicationViewModel, only the sub ones.

Comment: The only general applicatable advice: Avoid storing any data directly in static variables. static for Data is about as bad as goto. A class that need instantiation, assigned to a static field is the closest I ever got to using static.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I'd use the `ApplicationViewModel` with other ViewModels?

Comment: I tend to avoid static classes and definitely a controller should not be static or store info, it's not the controllers job. What I tend to do is have a settings class that stores/gets app-wide settings (you can cache in there to avoid storage access also).

Comment: Yeah I don't want to put too many arbitrary duties on my `Controller`, especially when it's just there to provide the Models and Switch pages

Comment: Why don't you place them in `MainMenuViewModel ` and then inherit the other viewmodels from it? Also, the word `controller` sounds like MVC so perhaps not a good name in an MVVM app (but no biggie).

Comment: ...Ok now I'm going to ask a dumb question: Can you have one ViewModel provide other ViewModels? Also, yeah, the `Controller` class is something I've been using since MVC with WinForms, but since I've done WPF I just implement it as the PageSwitcher out of habit. I could probably rename it to something a little more suitable though

Comment: Look at my answer, you shouldn't make your view models inherit from other types of view models like the main one, which has nothing to do with your view model...a view model should only represent the current view and nothing else. You could make a base view model that has common elements to your other view models though.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I did using MvvmCross, with an example for storing selected language (a global var needed). I also use the same pattern for versions, etc.  Here is part of my SettingsPreferences class:

```
public static string SelectedLanguage
{
    get { return Settings.AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(StringConstants.SelectedLanguage, SelectedLanguageDefault); }

    set { Settings.AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(StringConstants.SelectedLanguage, value); }
}

public static bool FirstRun
    {
        get { return Settings.AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(StringConstants.FirstRun, FirstRunDefault); }

        set { Settings.AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(StringConstants.FirstRun, value); }
    }

    public static int LatestUpdateVersion
    {
        get { return Settings.AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(StringConstants.LatestUpdateVersion, LatestUpdateVersionDefault); }

        set { Settings.AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(StringConstants.LatestUpdateVersion, value); }
    }

    public static string LatestUpdateVersionDate
    {
        get { return Settings.AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(StringConstants.LatestUpdateVersionDate, LatestUpdateVersionDateDefault); }

        set { Settings.AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(StringConstants.LatestUpdateVersionDate, value); }
    }
```

Settings is a wrapper to a nuget package for persisting stuff (supports Android, iOS, Windows Store (Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows Store 8.1) and WPF projects):

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static ISettings AppSettings
    {
        get
        {
            return CrossSettings.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my LanguageViewModel calls it simply like this:

```
var lang = SettingsPreferences.SelectedLanguage;
```

To update the setting, simply:

```
SettingsPreferences.SelectedLanguage = "en";
```

It can be anything really.